# Double conversion c++ opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, double

I'm having a hard time understanding my issue. The code is the following:

```
VideoCapture cap(argv[1]);
double fps = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);
int fps_prime =  (int)fps;
cout << "FPS = " << fps << endl;
cout << "FPS_prime = " << fps_prime << endl;
```

I know for sure that my input is 25 fps, but I'm getting the following output:

```
FPS = 2.60049e-07
FPS_prime = 0
Height = 576
```

How should I get the integer part of my fps ?
I should precise I'm using opencv 3.0 and I have the following preprocessor directive:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#ifdef _STDINT_H
#undef _STDINT_H
#endif
#include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

Comment: The problem is not double conversion. 2.60049e-07, 0.000000260049, a positive number less than 1, should convert to zero. It has no non-zero integer part to get. I suggest looking into why you are getting such a small number for your FPS.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. This seems related to a bug in openCV.